# Random color for circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, colors, draw

I'm using svg to draw a circle and I would like to make the stroke color and fill color the same, but still random. Is there some way to randomize the color?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [article](http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/) by Paul Irish about this problem.

```
'#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
```

Comment: +1. But note that this will (essentially) never generate perfect white.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColor(){
    return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}

var myColor = getColor();
```

and then just use `myColor` to set your stroke and fill.
This will generate pastel-like colors.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/29rkd/